# Сколько запятых нужно в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, уточнения

Попалось такое предложение:

*Над столом, в тени тяжелой плюшевой шторы улыбнулось бледное лицо.*

Очень хочется поставить запятую после "шторы", но объяснить свое желание не могу. Скажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли здесь вторая запятая или можно обойтись одной, а то и убрать ее, памятуя о "террасе вблизи конопляника". Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пунктуация будет зависеть от смысловых характеристик обстоятельств места.

1. Изначальное предложение, с одной запятой, говорит об однородности и равноправности (*бледное лицо улыбнулось* и ***над столом***, и ***в тени***). Такой вариант, как мне кажется, выглядит неуклюже. Если автор хотел передать именно этот смысл, то лучше соединить обстоятельства союзом ***И*** или вообще написать по-другому.
2. Мне тоже, как и Вам, хочется поставить вторую запятую, обособив уточнение:
   ***Над столом*** (где именно?) – ***в тени тяжелой плюшевой шторы***.
3. Но возможен вариант и без запятых. Тогда речь будет идти о столе, который сам находится в тени шторы.

[**Уточняющие члены предложения**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118,4) (Розенталь):

> В зависимости от смысла одни и те же слова могут рассматриваться или не рассматриваться как уточняющее обстоятельство. Ср.:
> ***Впереди на дороге** толпились люди* (т. е. в передней части дороги). — *Впереди, **на дороге,** толпились люди* (т. е. сама дорога находилась впереди);
> ***Далеко в лесу** раздавались удары топора* (слушатель находится в лесу). — *Далеко, **в лесу,** раздавались удары топора* (слушатель находится вне леса)...